# The transaction can get from Web3j but display as failed in Etherscan

Tags: etherscan, web3j

How could I get the real status from EthBlock.TransactionObject(replayPastBlocksFlowable) in Web3j as same as Etherscan?
I couldn't find any status items from Web3j response, how does Etherscan check the status?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3b89a03322520c517b36573fff64913bd9eee048e4d754a8d052d68ded78c3d2
[image]

Printing EthBlock.TransactionObject from Web3j

```
{
    "blockHash": "0x2010f10af7babf7c3a0e19b2257820ba5e317b3d322409605a0b2d330af88444",
    "transactionIndex": 204,
    "nonce": 1146,
    "input": "0x",
    "r": "0xc084063d387979c37488d0b22f4ad1c767efcf171f2a1ffd218177d4d12e5950",
    "s": "0x521aa34adbfdb2d5b80b58bb22c8e3899d95c638819bbcbda10bfe464d65ed9f",
    "v": 27,
    "blockNumber": 11151512,
    "gas": 21000,
    "from": "0x00a131e4c53066f5846372e3b0beac4f0b3310e0",
    "to": "0xdc7cd290867032e6a720334dc47f7a0329385adb",
    "value": 255000000000000000,
    "hash": "0x3b89a03322520c517b36573fff64913bd9eee048e4d754a8d052d68ded78c3d2",
    "gasPrice": 81400000000
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What Etherscan checks, and what you are looking for, is the transaction receipt, which includes the status.

There is a JSON-RPC call for this : `eth_getTransactionReceipt` (see here https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API).

I don't know web3j but the documentation refers to a method named `Web3j.ethGetTransactionReceipt(<txHash>)` (https://docs.web3j.io/transactions/transaction_mechanisms/).

Also have a look to this : [How can I get the TxReceipt of a transaction with web3j?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65178/how-can-i-get-the-txreceipt-of-a-transaction-with-web3j).

Comment: Thanks, it works. EthBlock.TransactionObject does not include the receipt so that I have to get the TransactionReceipt once more by the tx_hash.